# Command Not Found CentOS | .bat File

Tags: linux, windows, batch-file

Im trying to run a `.bat` file on my server through php `popen` command, ive struggled and finally got to the point where all the permissions are set correctly and now i can actually execute the file but i have a problem. In my server logs it displays

`foo.bat: line 1: mstsc: command not found, referer: http://dev.example.com`

The full code in the file is `mstsc /v:192.168.1.1` I know this means that it doesn't recognise the command on centos but im not sure what to do to fix the problem.

The aim of this code is to open RDP for the user who requested it. Bear in mind that this code works perfectly locally on my windows OS using xampp but when i upload it to the server running CENTOS it doesnt work.

**My question is**

How do i fix this error and allow CENTOS to execute a command that opens an RDP window for the user

Comment: You are expecting a Windows batch file to run on Linux?

Comment: @Squashman Instead of replying so blandly you could offer some advice your comment is not very helpful. A .bat file belongs to windows OS so hence it cannot be ran on your linux server system. Look here for running RDP from your web browser: http://superuser.com/questions/312011/can-you-launch-remote-desktop-via-url

Comment: @KenziieeFlavius, it was not a comment.  I asked a question.  The sentence ends in a question mark.

Comment: @Squashman then dont comment with another question, especially a rhetorical one. Bottom line is the user obviously is unsure that's why they are using stack to ask a question because they need help, you commenting with a rhetorical question **literally** helps nobody. Either way Rawns answer seems to have actually helped the OP.

Comment: @KenziieeFlavius, that is all your perception and opinion.  I asked a question.  Period. Wasn't a rhetorical question.

Comment: @KenziieeFlavius Thank you for the help, i figured it out eventually!

Comment: @YasminFrench No problem good to hear!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I feel like this is exactly what you're after

http://www.jjclements.co.uk/2010/02/21/rdp-hyperlink/

It allows you run a bat file that opens windows RDP without needing to write a single line of server code. Take a look its pretty good!

Comment: This still only seems to be usable in Windows when the user is running CentOS.

Comment: @Rawns this solution has nothing to do with CentOS at all theres no code needed for CentOS its strictly windows, it allows windows to handle rdp://whatever.ip.address and opens it in windows RDP. Seems like it was what the OP wanted

Comment: Exactly. See OP's original question: "How do i fix this error **and allow CENTOS** to execute a command that opens an RDP window for the user". You can't use your solution in CentOS to auto-open an RDP connection as your solution is specifically for Windows, **not** CentOS.

Comment: @Rawns The answer is.. you cannot as you quoted in your answer... 'It's not available to run on CentOS' so also like you said 'You'll need to use an alternative solution'. My answer is an alternative solution, just like yours so im not sure what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

MSTSC is a Windows RDP client which is why it works on Windows.

It's not available to run on CentOS, let alone call by executing a Windows batch file! You'll need to use an alternative solution like FreeRDP and use a script like this one if you want to do this from CentOS: https://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=CentOS_7&p=x&f=5